# URL in ZendFramewrok

Tags: php, url, zend-framework, pagination, url-routing

I have two Paginator in one page ,  I've created two pagintion control (pagination.phtml and pagination1.phtml) there are four state here: 
1- user clicks on **message**s paginator next -or preview-(ex. third section)
`http://website/admin/test/public/user/detail/user_id/9999999/message/3`

2- user clicks on **file**s paginator next -or preview-(ex. second section)
`http://website/admin/test/public/user/detail/user_id/9999999/file/2`

 In this two states everything is okay. my problem here:

3-user clicks on **message**s paginator next -or preview-(ex. third section) and next clicks on **file**s paginator next -or preview-(ex. second section)
`http://website/admin/test/public/user/detail/user_id/9999999/message/3/file/2`

4- user clicks on **file**s paginator next -or preview-(ex. second section) and next clicks on **message**s paginator next -or preview-(ex. third section)
`http://website/admin/test/public/user/detail/user_id/9999999/file/2/message/3`

I want to convert third state to second one , and also fourth to first.

Comment: 1) Are You using ZF or ZF2? 2) Could you, please, provide some code and its location, for example, for ZF2: `<project-name>\module\<module-name>\config\module.config.php` and the `'router' => array(...` part of it + your pagination.phtml and pagination1.phtml and their locations?

Comment: If you are using ZF 1.x, in pagination.phtml try this, `$this->url({params},null,true)`, ie. explicitily specifying the `$reset = true` (the third one) parameter